# Having problems to generate a random array and visualize it using <div> elements in VS Code?

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, dom, visualization

I am a beginner at web dev and am trying to build a sorting visualizer.
I am unable to get the output for generating a visualization of a random array  by using the (div)
element of html.

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>sorting visualizer</title>
    <style>
        /* *{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        } */
        #array_container{
            position: absolute;
            left: 100px;
            right: 100px;
            bottom: 100px;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            /* margin-left: 50px;
            margin-right: 50px; */
            background-color: turquoise;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        
        function random_array(min, max){
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
        
        function generate_array(){
            var cont = document.getElementById("array_container");
            var bar;
            var arr = [];
            for ( var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
                arr.push(random_array(5, 1000));
                bar = document.createElement("div");
                bar.style = "height:"+arr[i]+";width:2px;margin:0 1px;background-color:pink;display:inline-block;";
                cont.appendChild(bar);

            }
        }
        }
    </script>
    <div id="array_container">
        
    </div>
    <button id="btn1" onclick="generate_array">generate</button>
</body>
</html>
```

please help me by finding the ERROR and also suggest me some other methods for visualizing array in a bar graph format.

Comment: did you try F12 ?

Comment: it was mistyping i have removed it

Comment: Your brackets in the script are also a little off too, your final bracket should be before the declaration of `generate_array`. Maybe your code got a little garbled when you copied it over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple minor syntax bugs I found:

- You're missing the parenthesis `()` at the end of your function name when you pass it to the generate button's `onclick`
- The brackets around your functions were offset, which was causing errors

Your code isn't broken beyond those minor syntax bugs, the problem you're facing is that your generated `div`s aren't respecting the height you're passing them, because you didn't give them a *height unit*.

You need to specify a unit like `px`, otherwise the height will get thrown out and ignored.

Working example (You'll want to adjust some other styles if you want them to fit in your box):

```js
function random_array(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

function generate_array() {
  var cont = document.getElementById("array_container");
  var bar;
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    arr.push(random_array(5, 1000));
    bar = document.createElement("div");
    bar.style = "height:" + arr[i] + "px;width:2px;margin:0 1px;background-color:pink;display:inline-block;";
    cont.appendChild(bar);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>sorting visualizer</title>
  <style>
    #array_container {
      position: absolute;
      left: 100px;
      right: 100px;
      bottom: 100px;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: turquoise;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="array_container"></div>
  <button id="btn1" onclick="generate_array()">generate</button>
</body>
</html>
```